# Windows 7 - Cannot move or copy things to the folder

Tags: windows-7

Just a minute ago I had to remove a virus from that folder. It was removed and I had to restart my computer because of it. It's now successfully removed but whenever I try to move or copy something to that folder, it says I need administrative permissions. Although I'm on my administrator account, whenever I click continue (with the admin icon) it still says I need administrative approval and shows the "Try again" or "Cancel" options. I can click try again so many times and it keeps popping up.

Comment: You need to take ownership of said folder. Follow the instructions [here](http://windows.mercenie.com/windows-xp/take-ownership-permission-of-files-folder-in-windows-7-and-xp-to-access-those-completely/).